# Updating a database info when a file is updated in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database(MySQL) table which stores the link of files that can be downloaded and it also contains the last time these files were updated.

I would like the time values(timestamps) in the database table to change whenever I run a code to update the files in the FileManager in the cPanel.

How do I do that in php? I tried searching, but to no avail. Need some guidance on this.

So far what I have done is to create a interface so that I can insert files in the database using SB Admin v2.0. This takes care of updating the timevalue. However, I do not need the interface because I will run a code to update the files.

So what I am looking at is how to get the last modified time of a file using PHP?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Nothing yet. Need help to start on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating files system via external script (not PHP) than you need to "listen" to files. To do so, use Cron Job to run this (pseudo) code.

```
$files = array(
    'file1.txt' => array('timestamp' => '12345678'),
    'file2.txt' => array('timestamp' => '12346879'),
);

$target = '/uploads'; 
$weeds = array('.', '..'); 
$uploadedFiles = array_diff(scandir($target), $weeds); 

foreach ($uploadedFiles as $filename) {
    if (isset($files[$filename])) {
        if ($files[$filename]['timestamp'] < filemtime($filename)) {
            $db->update('UPDATE files SET timestamp = :timestamp WHERE file_name = :filename');
            $db->params = array_merge($db->params, array(':filename' => $filename, ':timestamp' => $files[$filename]['timestamp']));
        }
    } else {
        $db->insert(getFileInfo($filename));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/crodas/WatchFiles . Example code taken from README .

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use WatchFiles\Watch;

// we'd like to watch some files
// and to save its state in foobar.php
$foobar = new Watch("foobar.php");
if ($foobar->isWatching()) {
  if (!$foobar->hasChanged()) {
    // somebody else before us started watching files/dirs
    // on foobar.php and *nothing* changed since last 
    // time
    return;
  }
  // do heavy stuff here (Recompile it?)
  // we need to tell the watch that we're aware of lastest
  // changes and we'd like to update the file modification time
  $foobar->rebuild();
  return;
}

// we'd love to see when a new file has been added or deleted
$foobar->watchDir("foodir");
$foobar->watchDirs(array("foodir", 'foobar'));

// or monitor changes inside file or files
$foobar->watchFile("foodir.php");
$foobar->watchFiles(array("foodir.php", 'foobar.php'));

// start watching!
$foobar->watch();
```